# Proof that value at risk is monotonic

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, mathematical-modeling

can u help me? anybody can exlpanie me about the proof of the monotonic

() is a monotonic

If  ≤ , so  () ≤  ().

Take  =  where  ≥ 1, so,

() = inf{: ( > ) ≤ }

() = inf{: ( > ) ≤ }

= inf{:  ( > y/c ) ≤ }

= inf{: ( > ) ≤ } (assume y/c = )

=  inf{: ( > ) ≤ }

=   ().

If I take  != , how come the  () is a monotonic?

Comment: What is "Vara"? Also be sure to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Yes i am sure, "Vara" is a VaR

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion follows quite directly from the definitions. Let $X\leq Y$ be two stochastic variables. Then, for each $c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $P(X>c) \leq P(Y>c)$.

Fixing $c^{*} = \inf\{c \in \mathbb{R} | P(X>c) \leq{\alpha}\} := VaR_{\alpha}(X)$ and using the fact that $P(Y> c^{*}) \geq P(X>c^{*})$, the conclusion follows.